# angularJS - how to validate if number is in string

Tags: angularjs, regex, validation, angularjs-directive

I have some input-fields (text) for name, firstname, city, etc.
now i want to validate if the value contains only chars (a-z, A-Z).. if the value would be "val1" the function should return a error.

I have no idea how this would be done, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, Have you tried any code for validate this??

Comment: You can check if the form is valid with [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern).

Comment: Why? What if someone's name or city contains a hyphen, apostrophe, Unicode character such as `é` or a Chinese character, etc?

Comment: @Aleksey Soloveyyes i have tried ´ng-pattern´ but somehow it does not work

Comment: @ctwheels I simply don't want to allow numbers in names

Comment: @css `ng-pattern` validates with `$valid`, which it gets from the `name` and not `ng-model`; have you tried adding something like `name="form"`, `name="input"` (on form and input fields) and validating with `$scope.form.input.$valid`?

Comment: @css then just use the pattern `\D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vary vague and has no code of your own to show us what you have already tried. Please, next time try to solve your problem on your own before posting here. Try to build on the code below. I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
<div ng-controller='ctrl'>
   <input type='text' ng-model='myInput' ng-change="validate()>
</div>

module.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.validate= function() {
        return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($scope.myInput);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: I have tried various attempts, but with no effort yet .. now with your example.. how would I pass a var to ´validate()´?

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_fname" ng-model="form_fname" ng-change="validate({{form_fname}})"  placeholder="Vorname">

Comment: you can access input's value from your $scope. $scope.form_fname

Comment: yes, but I would like to pass various values to that function..  like ´ng-change="validate(form_fname)´

Comment: you can pass form_fname as a string like validate('form_fname') and then use it like this $scope.validate= function(name) {
        return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test($scope[name]);
    }

Comment: thank you very much bro ;) .. you helped me a lot :))

Comment: Happy to help. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

just add ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z]*$/" to the input elements.